# input keyup jquery function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, input

I have a situation like the one below:

```js
var value = document.getElementById("value").value;
if (value = 'a') {
  ('.setting').append('<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="carname">');
}
elseif(value = 'b') {
  ('.setting').append('<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="fruitname">');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name=name]").keyup(function() {
    alert("The text has been changed.");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="your name">
<select id="value"></select>
<div class="setting"></div>
```

The problem I have is that when I change the input the alert does not trigger. Does anyone know were am I messing up?

Comment: `$("input[name=name]")` should be `$("input[name=username]")`. Typo.

Comment: You also have `if (value = 'a')` instead of `if (value == 'a')` and `elseif` instead of `else if`. And missing `$`s `$('.setting')`

Comment: well you've a lot of typos, fix it and try.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to select an `input` whose `name` property is `"name"`, but the value you set in your HTML is `name="username"`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='username']").keyup(function(){
        alert("The text has been changed.");
    });
});
```

A better way yet is to give your input a unique `id` and select by that, so you don't have to use an attribute selector:

```html
<input id="usernameInput" type="text" name="username" placeholder="your name">
```

```js
$("#usernameInput").keyup(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$` is missing from `('.setting')`, you should use `.on` to catch events of dynamically created elements and it's better to use it with classes, also use `==` or more likely `===` for conditions.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/cuhibup/1/edit?html,output)

Your code modified:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="example" placeholder="your name">
<select id="value"></select>
<div class="setting"></div>

<script>
  var value = document.getElementById("value").value;
  if(value==='a'){
    $('.setting').append('<input type="text" name="name" class="example" placeholder="carname">');
  }

  else if(value==='b'){
    $('.setting').append('<input type="text" name="name" class="example" placeholder="fruitname">');
  }
</script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('keyup', '.example', function() {
     alert("The text has been changed.");
   });
 });
</script>
```